# Apollo, NextJS, and API Route failed to display content

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to setup data fetching with Next.JS, GraphQL and Next.JS based on this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y34ym0-KZ8A&ab_channel=LeighHalliday

It works smoothly on dev, yarn build was successful, deploying to vercel is successful without any error, but it shows forever spinning and "page is not responsive" alert when I run `yarn start` (or deploy it).
Here is the preview: https://nanohome-qqm9vohmt-vader1359.vercel.app/

Here is my setup:

```
// schema

import { gql } from "apollo-server"

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Media {
    long: String
    video: String
    closeup: String
    lifestyle_1: String
    lifestyle_2: String
    photometric: String
    designerPhoto: String
  }
  type Variant {
    variantID: ID
    sku: String
    size: String
    brand: String
    media: Media
    price: String
    brandID: ID
    category: String
    designer: String
    inventory: String
    categoryID: ID
    productLine: String
    productName: String
    subCategory: String
    variantSlug: String
    packshotSize: String
    variantColor: String
    groupCategory: String
    subCategoryID: ID
    variantNoSize: String
    productInfo_en: String
    designerInfo_en: String
    groupCategoryID: ID
    packshotDetails: String
    variant: String
    productID: ID
  }
  input VariantsFilters {
    brand: String
    category: String
    designer: String
    groupCategory: String
    subCategory: String
    categoryID: ID
    groupCategoryID: ID
    subCategoryID: ID
    productID: ID
  }
  input VariantsFiltersInput  {
    filters: VariantsFilters
  }
  
  
  type Query {
    getVariant(slug: String): Variant
    getVariants (input: VariantsFiltersInput): [Variant]
  }
`
```

Resolver:

// resolvers

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getVariants: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("https://api.npoint.io/66dd36a7cd271ea72aa0")
        const variantsData = await res.json()

        const { filters } = args.input || {}
        const shouldApplyFilters = filters !== null && filters !== undefined

        context.variants = variantsData.variants

        let filteredVariants = context.variants

        if (!shouldApplyFilters) {
          return filteredVariants
        }

        const shouldApplyProductIDFilter =
          filters.productID !== null && filters.productID !== undefined

        const shouldApplyBrandFilter =
          filters.brand !== null && filters.brand !== undefined

        const shouldApplyCategoryFilter =
          filters.category !== null && filters.category !== undefined

        const shouldApplyGroupCategoryFilter =
          filters.groupCategory !== null && filters.groupCategory !== undefined

        const shouldApplySubCategoryFilter =
          filters.subCategory !== null && filters.subCategory !== undefined

        const shouldApplyCategoryIDFilter =
          filters.categoryID !== null && filters.categoryID !== undefined

        const shouldApplyGroupCategoryIDFilter =
          filters.groupCategoryID !== null &&
          filters.groupCategoryID !== undefined

        const shouldApplySubCategoryIDFilter =
          filters.subCategoryID !== null && filters.subCategoryID !== undefined

        if (shouldApplyProductIDFilter) {
          filteredVariants = filteredVariants.filter(
            (a) => a.productID === filters.productID
          )
        }

        if (shouldApplyBrandFilter) {
          filteredVariants = filteredVariants.filter(
            (a) => a.brand === filters.brand
          )
        }

        if (shouldApplyCategoryFilter) {
          filteredVariants = filteredVariants.filter(
            (a) => a.category === filters.category
          )
        }

        if (shouldApplyGroupCategoryFilter) {
          filteredVariants = filteredVariants.filter(
            (a) => a.groupCategory === filters.groupCategory
          )
        }
        if (shouldApplySubCategoryFilter) {
          filteredVariants = filteredVariants.filter(
            (a) => a.subCategory === filters.subCategory
          )
        }
        if (shouldApplyCategoryIDFilter) {
          filteredVariants = filteredVariants.filter(
            (a) => a.categoryID === filters.categoryID
          )
        }
        if (shouldApplyGroupCategoryIDFilter) {
          filteredVariants = filteredVariants.filter(
            (a) => a.groupCategoryID === filters.groupCategoryID
          )
        }

        if (shouldApplySubCategoryIDFilter) {
          filteredVariants = filteredVariants.filter(
            (a) => a.subCategoryID === filters.subCategoryID
          )
        }

        return filteredVariants
      } catch (error) {
        throw error
      }
    },
    getVariant: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const { slug } = args
      if (context.variants && context.variants.length > 0) {
        return context.variants.find((a) => a.variantSlug == slug)
      } else {
        try {
          const res = await fetch("https://api.npoint.io/66dd36a7cd271ea72aa0")
          const variantsData = await res.json()

          context.variants = variantsData.variants

          return context.variants.find((a) => a.variantSlug == slug)
        } catch (error) {
          throw error
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
```

file graphql.js

```
import { ApolloServer, gql, makeExecutableSchema } from "apollo-server-micro"

import { resolvers } from "./resolvers"
import { typeDefs } from "./schemas"

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })
const startServer = apolloServer.start()

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'https://studio.apollographql.com'
  )
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  )
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.end()
    return false
  }

  await startServer
  await apolloServer.createHandler({
    path: '/api/graphql',
  })(req, res)
}

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
}
```

apoloClient.js

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "apollo-boost"

import { concatPagination } from "@apollo/client/utilities"
import isEqual from "lodash/isEqual"
import merge from "deepmerge"
import { useMemo } from "react"

let apolloClient

function createIsomorphicLink() {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    // server
    const { SchemaLink } = require("@apollo/client/link/schema")
    const { schema } = require("../pages/api/index")
    return new SchemaLink({ schema })
  } else {
    // client
    const { HttpLink } = require("@apollo/client/link/http")
    return new HttpLink({ uri: "/api/graphql" })
  }
}

function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === "undefined",
    link: createIsomorphicLink(),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })
}

export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {
  const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient()
  if (initialState) {
    _apolloClient.cache.restore(initialState)
  }

  if (typeof window === "undefined") return _apolloClient
  apolloClient = apolloClient ?? _apolloClient
  return apolloClient
}

export function useApollo(initialState) {
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(initialState), [initialState])
  return store
}
```

and the component:

```
import tw, { styled } from "twin.macro"

import Head from "next/head"
import { Pagination } from "antd"
import ProductCardCarousel from "../../components/ProductCard/ProductCardCarousel"
import ProductCardGrid from "../../components/ProductCard/ProductCardGrid"
import ProductEqualCardCarousel from "./ProductEqualCardCarousel"
import Space from "../../components/General/Space"
import { addPath } from "graphql/jsutils/Path"
import { gql } from "apollo-boost"
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks"
import { useRecoilState } from "recoil"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import { useState } from "react"

export const ALL_VARIANTS_QUERY = gql`
  query Query($getVariantsInput: VariantsFiltersInput) {
    getVariants(input: $getVariantsInput) {
      variantID
      price
      packshotDetails
      variantSlug
      variantNoSize
      variant
      packshotSize
      productLine
      designer
      productInfo_en
      brand
      media {
        long
      }
    }
  }
`

const ProductsSection = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const currentURL = new URL(url + router.asPath)
  let subCategoryIDParams = currentURL.searchParams.get("subCategoryID")
  let categoryIDParams = currentURL.searchParams.get("categoryID")

  console.log(router)

  console.log(currentURL)
  console.log(categoryIDParams)

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(ALL_VARIANTS_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      getVariantsInput: {
        filters: {
          subCategoryID: subCategoryIDParams,
          categoryID: categoryIDParams,
        },
      },
    },
  })

  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(24)
  const [totalPage, setTotalPage] = useState(0)
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const [minIndex, setMinIndex] = useState(0)
  const [maxIndex, setMaxIndex] = useState(pageSize)

  const handlePaginationChange = (page, pageSize) => {
    setPage((prevPage) => {
      page != prevPage &&
        document.querySelector("body").scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" })
      return page
    })

    setPageSize(pageSize)
    setMinIndex((page - 1) * pageSize)
    setMaxIndex(page * pageSize)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("prevPath", window.sessionStorage.getItem("prevPath"))
    if (data) {
      return () => {
        setTotalPage(data.getVariants.length / pageSize)
      }
    }

    console.log(router)

    const handleRouteChange = (url, { shallow }) => {
      console.log(
        `App is changing to ${url} ${
          shallow ? "with" : "without"
        } shallow routing`
      )
    }

    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange)
  }, [data, pageSize, router.events, router])

  if (loading) return <span>LOADING...</span>

  return (
    <S.Container>
      <Head>
        <title>nanoHome</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main tw="w-full">
        <S.ProductSection>
          {data && (
            <ProductCardGrid
              variants={data.getVariants.slice(minIndex, maxIndex)}
            />
          )}
          <Space size="small" />
          {data && (
            <S.PaginationWrapper>
              <Pagination
                tw="my-auto"
                onChange={handlePaginationChange}
                pageSize={pageSize}
                defaultCurrent={1}
                current={page}
                total={data.getVariants.length}
                hideOnSinglePage
              />
            </S.PaginationWrapper>
          )}
        </S.ProductSection>

        <Space size="medium" />
        {/* {data && (
          <S.RecommendationSection>
            <S.SectionTitle>Our Recommendations</S.SectionTitle>
            <Space size="medium" />
            <ProductEqualCardCarousel />
          </S.RecommendationSection>
        )} */}
      </main>
    </S.Container>
  )
}

const S = {}

S.Container = styled.div``

export default ProductsSection

S.Container = styled.div`
  ${tw`flex flex-col items-center min-h-screen`}
`

S.FilterWrapper = styled.div`
  ${tw`flex w-full h-20 m-auto align-middle lg:max-w-4xl xl:max-w-screen-xl 2xl:max-w-screen-2xl`}
`

S.SearchBarWrapper = styled.div`
  ${tw`md:hidden lg:block lg:w-50r xl:w-60r`}
`

S.ProductSection = styled.section`
  ${tw`w-full m-auto md:max-w-2xl lg:max-w-4xl xl:max-w-screen-xl 2xl:max-w-screen-2xl`}
`

S.PaginationWrapper = styled.div`
  ${tw`flex justify-center w-full`}
`

S.RecommendationSection = styled.section`
  ${tw`m-auto lg:max-w-4xl xl:max-w-screen-xl 2xl:max-w-screen-2xl`}
`
S.SectionTitle = styled.h1`
  ${tw`font-serif text-2xl text-center md:text-3xl lg:text-4xl`}
`
```

and the products page component with getStaticProps

```
import ProductsSection, {
  ALL_VARIANTS_QUERY,
} from "../components/ProductCard/ProductsSection"
import { addApolloState, initializeApollo } from "../lib/apolloClient"
import tw, { styled } from "twin.macro"

import Head from "next/head"
import Space from "../components/General/Space"
import fetch from "node-fetch"
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo()

  await apolloClient.query({
    query: ALL_VARIANTS_QUERY,
  })
  return {
    props: {
      initialApolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract(),
    },
  }
}

const products = () => {


  return (
    <S.Container>
      <Head>
        <title>nanoHome</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main tw="w-full">
        <Space size="medium" />
        {/* <ProductsSection /> */}

        <Space size="medium" />
      </main>
    </S.Container>
  )
}

const S = {}

S.Container = styled.div``

export default products

S.Container = styled.div`
  ${tw`flex flex-col items-center min-h-screen`}
`

S.FilterWrapper = styled.div`
  ${tw`flex w-full h-20 m-auto align-middle lg:max-w-4xl xl:max-w-screen-xl 2xl:max-w-screen-2xl`}
`

S.SearchBarWrapper = styled.div`
  ${tw`md:hidden lg:block lg:w-50r xl:w-60r`}
`

S.ProductSection = styled.section`
  ${tw`w-full m-auto md:max-w-2xl lg:max-w-4xl xl:max-w-screen-xl 2xl:max-w-screen-2xl`}
`
```

There is no error so I'm lost.

- The build before adding apollo works nicely on vercel, so I'm pretty sure it's related to apollo.
- The data fetching API works well on Apollo Studio.
- Page build is succesful.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Your vercel preview not working for me

Comment: That's what I'm asking. It's not working even it run well on dev and build succesfully.